# Can I test Google Play In-App Review in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm learning [Google Play In-App Review](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#when-to-request) .

I run Code A in Android Emulator, I hope to display Google in-app review UI just like Image A, but I get only the info "aa" which means request failed.

Can I test Google Play In-App Review in Android Emulator?

**Code A**

```
val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(mContext)
   
    val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()
   //val manager = FakeReviewManager(mContext)
 
    request.addOnCompleteListener { request ->
                if (request.isSuccessful) {
                    // We got the ReviewInfo object
                    val reviewInfo = request.result


                    val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(mActivity, reviewInfo)
                    flow.addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
                        // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
                        // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
                        // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
                        Log.e("my","cc")
                    }

                    Log.e("my","bb")

                } else {
                    Log.e("my","aa")
                    // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
                }
     }
```

**Image A**
[image]

Comment: add the followin line in your 'else' code :  @ReviewErrorCode val reviewErrorCode = (task.getException() as TaskException).errorCode .. and log the reviewErrorCode  or the log the task.getException

Answer (score 0):

In-app reviews require your app to be published in Play Store. However, you can test your integration without publishing your app to production using either internal test tracks or internal app sharing. Both methods are described in this section.

**Test using an internal test track**
Upload your app to the internal test track and install it on a device with a user account that has access to the internal test track. When using an internal test track, the following conditions must be met:

1. The user account is part of the Internal Test Track.
2. The user account is the primary account and it's selected in the Play Store.
3. The user account has downloaded the app from the Play Store (the app
   is listed in the user's Google Play library).
4. The user account does not currently have a review for the app.

After the account on the device has downloaded the app at least once from the internal test track and is part of the testers list, you can deploy new versions of the app locally to that device (for example, using Android Studio).

**Test using internal app sharing**
Alternatively, for rapid iteration you can use internal app sharing to test your integration. This method lets you quickly test changes by skipping some of the verification that happens with other test tracks.

You can get more information here https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test